# WPF Flash A Border But not the Children

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

Any ideas on how to flash a border but not the children inside?

I can flash the border like so:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="valueFlasher" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="outline">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0.2"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="7" x:Name="outline">
   <!--children--> 
</Border>
```

But that will change the opacity of everything nested inside.

I was thinking something like this:

```
<Border BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="7">
    <Border.BorderBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" x:Name="outline"/>
    </Border.BorderBrush>
    <!--children-->
</Border>
```

But it doesn't seem to work either. Maybe my storyboard can't find 'outline' because its nested?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property path `(UIElement.Opacity)` is not valid for SolidColorBrush, because it is not a UIElement.

---

Instead, use `BorderBrush.Opacity`

```
<Storyboard x:Key="valueFlasher" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.Opacity" 
        Storyboard.TargetName="outline">

        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0.2"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="1"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

with a Border like this:

```
<Border x:Name="outline" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="7">
    <Border.BorderBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Black"/>
    </Border.BorderBrush>
    <!--children-->
</Border>
```

---

Or just `Opacity`

```
<Storyboard x:Key="valueFlasher" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
        Storyboard.TargetName="outline">

        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0.2"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="1"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

with the `x:Name` set on the SolidColorBrush:

```
<Border BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="7">
    <Border.BorderBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Name="outline" Color="Black"/>
    </Border.BorderBrush>
    <!--children-->
</Border>
```

Comment: Such an obvious fix once I saw it.. Thank you! :)